# Нужны ли кавычки после двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

> Ответил, что сам нищий, езжу автостопом, сплю на улице, подытожив: 25–30 долларов и не больше.

Не пойму, нужны ли кавычки после двоеточия, или это необязательно?

Answer (score 2):

**Ответил, что сам нищий, езжу автостопом, сплю на улице, подытожив: 25–30 долларов,  и не больше.**

1) Кавычки не нужны, это не дословное высказывание, а пересказ содержания.

2) Оборот ***и не больше*** обособляется.

Вопрос № 232747

Какой синтаксической конструкцией являются сочетания "и не больше"? 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка: ***И не больше*** – присоединительная конструкция, обособляется.

3) Вызывает сомнение правильность употребления деепричастного оборота (в части последовательности действий):

Возможное редактирование: **Ответил, что сам нищий, езжу автостопом, сплю на улице, и подытожил: 25–30 долларов, не больше.**

Answer (score 0):

Вам как автору должно быть виднее, это дословное высказывание или нет. В зависимости от этого решается вопрос о кавычках.

По поводу обособления слов "и не больше". Поиск в Нацкорпусе дает три варианта:
с запятой, тире и без обособления. Обратите внимание: у Домбровского есть два варианта из трех. Возможно, распространенность текста влияет?

> Я-то так и понял: это приём публициста, **и не больше**. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Обезьяна приходит за своим черепом. Пролог (1943-1958)]
>
> ― И она так же отвечает ― я ей про Или и с кем его захватили, а она мне: «Ну вот видите, товарищ следователь, я же сразу вам сказала, что у нас были чисто товарищеские отношения **и не больше**. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 4 (1978)]
>
> Не освобождая от необходимости выбора позиции, она помогала сделать этот выбор ― прежде всего результатами исследовании, которые теперь никто тебе не предписывал, но которые тем более требовали качественного профессионального инструментария ― **и не больше**. [Ирина Прусс. Разве бывают такие академики? Особенно в общественных науках... // «Знание-сила», 2013]

Answer (score 0):

***Ответил, что сам нищий, езжу автостопом, сплю на улице, подытожив: "Двадцать пять - тридцать долларов — и не больше".***

Кавычки здесь желательны, так как вторая часть предложения представляет собой **прямую** речь, точно передающую интонацию, экспрессивность высказывания:...*"Двадцать пять - тридцать долларов — и не больше"*.

В первой части используется речь косвенная, приблизительно, неточно передающая суть высказывания: ... *что сам нищий, езжу автостопом, сплю на улице*...